# Summing all - / + values from a column by a specific year

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have joined 2 tables. One table has all the values (+/- amounts) and the other has mainly dimensional data. Once joining, I wanted to run a query to sum of all negative and positive values given a specific year.

Problem seems to be happening on the third line. Any thoughts?

```
select sum(sales_amount)
from salesInfo s inner joint dimInfo d
where sales_amount <0 and year = '2019';
```

The query is not generating due to an error being thrown on line 3:

> error - ORA-00905: missing keyword 00905. 00000 - "missing keyword"

Comment: *Problem seems to be happening*... what problem?

Comment: problem - the query not generating due to an error being thrown on line 3

Comment: If you get an error, please share the error message.

Comment: `join`, not `joint`.

Comment: error is throwing off on the last line (where year = 2019;) I've tried adding/removing apostrophes and nothing yet.

Comment: *the query not generating due to an error*... what error? Please provide specific message.

Comment: error - ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword" / it is stemming from the last line (where sales_amount .... //)

Comment: Not sure why the down vote happened. Might've been the rudimentary question or the proper structure of asking a question and placing the error message. Regardless, thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is likely due to the missing `ON` clause which in Oracle SQL is not allowed for `INNER JOIN` unlike other database dialects which treats such a join equivalent to a cross join.

Alternatively, you can use Oracle's `NATURAL JOIN` to join on matching named columns between tables:

```
from salesInfo s natural join dimInfo d
```

Either way, you can then run a conditional aggregate and even group by *year*:

```
select year,
       sum(case when sales_amount < 0 then sales_amount end) as negative_sales,
       sum(case when sales_amount > 0 then sales_amount end) as positive_sales
from salesInfo s 
inner join dimInfo d on s.some_id = d.some_id
group by year
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/SOHHE2409)

Comment: Thank you that did it. Much appreciated. it was the on clause as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Add an ON clause after the JOIN statement to specify the JOIN condition

```
SELECT sum(sales_amount)
FROM salesInfo s 
INNER JOIN dimInfo d
ON d.<column_name> = s.<column_name> 
WHERE sales_amount < 0 and year = '2019'
```

Comment: Awesome, this did it as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when sales_amount < 0 then sales_amount end) as neg_sum,
       sum(case when sales_amount > 0 then sales_amount end) as pos_sum          
from salesInfo s inner join
     dimInfo d
     on ? = ?  -- whatever your `JOIN` conditions are here
where year = 2019;
```

Comment: @dreweezy, make another try now!

Comment: Hi jarlh - yes I used join and not joint xD. I have tried this again and the error is throwing off on the last line (where year = 2019;) I've tried adding/removing apostrophes and still no luck.